# Form without focus/activation

Tags: winforms, focus, activation

I want to implement intellisense-like feature for my multiline textbox. The intellisense control is placed in standard form without control box (so, no title or maximize/minimze bottons are visible).

All works fine, but if intellisense-form is shown and user clicks into the intellisense form, the main form lost focus (so, user must click back into textbox for writing).

I know `ShowWithoutActivation` property, but it works only on activation, not on "standard focus".

**EDIT:**

I found the help on http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/273724 , but the presented code does not work. It throws "Invalid parameter" exception during "Show()" method.

Comment: Why u don't use a control instead of a form for intellisense?

Comment: Because customer want the intellisense form can overflow from main form.

Comment: Clearly your 'intellisense control' is not a control.  Pretty unguessable what kind of an animal it really is.  If it is a Form then set its TopLevel property to false to turn it into a control.

Comment: @Hans Passant: UserControl is in form. Form is shown via "Show()" method. Property "TopMost" set to "true", but it is not related with focus of form :(.

Comment: Well, of course it is.  A control doesn't have a TopMost property.  Clearly it is a form, use the TopLevel property.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Ok, if I use TopLevel property on control and show it outside of form, the control's behaviour is like form. So the control still takes focus and main form loose focus.

Answer (score 10):

To show the form without activation, override the ShowWithoutActivation property

```
protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
{
  get { return true; }
}
```

And if you do not want to activate the form even on mouse clicks, override the CreateParams and set these styles

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
  get
  {
    CreateParams p = base.CreateParams;

    p.Style |= 0x40000000; // WS_CHILD
    p.ExStyle |= 0x8000000; // WS_EX_NOACTIVATE - requires Win 2000 or higher :)

    return p;
  }
}
```

Comment: ExStyle is an int, so this doesn't compile on recent .NET versions. Also, that last suggestion about adjusting the CreateParams, even when modified to compile, doesn't work. You just get "Error creating window handle" Win32Exception

Answer (score 1):

i have a code somedays i downloaded from code project (i think ) and i dont what is the original download link  try using this

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Balloon.NET
{
    public class BalloonWindow : Form
    {
        public static readonly int TIPMARGIN;
        public static readonly int TIPTAIL;

        public BalloonWindow();

        public Point AnchorPoint { get; set; }
        public BalloonWindow.BallonQuadrant Quadrant { get; }

        public static Point AnchorPointFromControl(Control anchorControl);
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing);
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e);
        protected virtual Rectangle OnNCCalcSize(Rectangle windowRect);
        protected virtual void OnNCPaint(Graphics g);
        protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e);
        protected void RecalcLayout();
        protected void RepositionWindow(Point oldAnchorPoint, Point newAnchorPoint);
        public void ShowBalloon(Control anchorControl);
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m);

        public enum BallonQuadrant
        {
            TopLeft = 0,
            TopRight = 1,
            BottomLeft = 2,
            BottomRight = 3,
        }
    }
}
```

and use this form as follow

```
Balloon.NET.BalloonWindow ms = new Balloon.NET.BalloonWindow();
private void numberEdit1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ms.Visible)
    {
        ms.ShowBalloon(numberEdit1);
        numberEdit1.Focus();
    }
}
```