# Modal dialog button clicks won't respond for long time

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog, click

We have a weird customer issue which can not be reproduced through development environment. We see it happening on customer environment but no way we can reproduce it in any other environment we have. This makes it hard to solve the issue and that is why I need some help.

The issue is, whenever there is a modal dialog with "OK" / "Cancel" buttons and when user clicks on any of those it takes lot of time for that dialog to respond and disappear. The second time same dialog is shown the clicks respond bit faster.
We observed this mainly for modal dialog and not for non modal dialog.

one special thing we do before showing modal dialog is we create a new form which sits between Main Form and modal dialog. This new form is created to give blur effect to clearly indicate that you have to take some action on modal dialog before you can go back to main form. This was done for UI effect and here is the code for that,

```
private void BaseModalForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Some dialogs are not modal (For example Options Dialog ), still derived   from BaseModalForm .. Give the blur effect only when its a modal dialog.
  if (this.Modal)
  {
      Global.ModalDialogCount += 1;
      if (Global.MainForm != null && !Global.MainForm.IsDisposed)
      {
          // Create the white layer which would be rendered on top of the Main Window once the modal dialog appears, to give prominence to the modal dialog
          // Show the white layer only when first modal dialog is shown
        if (Global.MainForm.Visible && Global.ModalDialogCount == 1)
        {
          CreateWhiteLayerForm();
          whiteLayerForm.Show(Global.MainForm);
          whiteLayerForm.Enabled = false;
         }
      }
  }
}

private void CreateWhiteLayerForm()
{
    whiteLayerForm = new Form();

    int titleHeight = SystemInformation.CaptionHeight;
    int borderHeight = SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Height;
    int borderWidth = SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Width;

    // The white layer should not cover the title bar
    whiteLayerForm.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(Global.MainForm.Size.Width, Global.MainForm.Size.Height - titleHeight);
    whiteLayerForm.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Global.MainForm.Location.X , Global.MainForm.Location.Y + borderHeight + titleHeight);
    whiteLayerForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;

    whiteLayerForm.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.None;
    whiteLayerForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;

    whiteLayerForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    whiteLayerForm.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    whiteLayerForm.Opacity = 0.5;
}

private void BaseModalForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    if(whiteLayerForm != null)
        whiteLayerForm.Dispose();
    if(this.Modal)
      Global.ModalDialogCount -= 1;
}
```

This code always worked until we got this weird issue at customer environment. I am suspecting this might cause the clicks not to respond.

But it may be wrong. Is it possible that some anti virus program on customer environment blocks the click? This issue is happening to lot of people in that environment.

Can there be any other reason? Has anyone come across this anytime? Any help is appreciated. Let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: Does the customer maybe use Citrix, Remote Desktop, Hyper-V or some other form of remote access to the desktop? Painting the partly opaque form might take some time in this case.

Comment: Is this typcial behaviour for other applications as well? Do you see any difference for modal dialogs without the whiteLayerForm? What are the differences between the client's hardware/software and the developer's hardware/software? Compare the OS, 32/64 bit, processor, installed .NET framework, multple screens. You say a lot of other customers in that environment, but not all? Are there specific actions (network, database) in the closing or dispose event? I think the best thing to do is to add logging to a file and follow the events (with timer) to determine where the delay(s) occur.

Comment: I would start reducing the potential causes by first eliminating the `WhiteLayerForm` (for instance putting `return;` at the beginning of the `CreateWhiteLayerForm` method) and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, we have suppressed showing of white layer form and sent to customer to verify if its better since we can reproduce it in our environment. Waiting for customer response. Can anti virus program like McAfee slow these things or block things? Or any specific software we can check for?

Comment: If the issue occurs when pressing either button, the problem lies in whatever code is run when the dialog is being disposed. Have you tried having a  log generated with the time it takes to complete certain actions once the OK/Cancel button has been clicked?

Comment: What I would do is create the white layer form from a custom derived Form, so you can override ShowWithoutActivation as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10764646/403671  this would ensure this layer is really passive/inert. Difficult to say more w/o any reproduction code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be in some other application, that indiscriminately and incorrectly set hooks on window objects of other applications.

I saw the same situation on workstation with Punto Switcher installed. Try to get rid of keyboard switchers, in-tray dictionaries, debug tools, key loggers and do not forget viruses :).

Answer (score 0):

### Graphics Variables

Despite using the same code, graphics rendering will take varying lengths of time depending on the machine running and rendering the application, you cannot assume that any section of graphics code will run optimally on all devices.

Therefore this code is highly suspect, and should be able to reproduce it by asking detailed questions about the deployed environments graphics systems.

```
private void CreateWhiteLayerForm()
{
    whiteLayerForm = new Form();

    int titleHeight = SystemInformation.CaptionHeight;
    int borderHeight = SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Height;
    int borderWidth = SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Width;

    // The white layer should not cover the title bar
    whiteLayerForm.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(Global.MainForm.Size.Width, Global.MainForm.Size.Height - titleHeight);
    whiteLayerForm.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Global.MainForm.Location.X , Global.MainForm.Location.Y + borderHeight + titleHeight);
    whiteLayerForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;

    whiteLayerForm.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.None;
    whiteLayerForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;

    whiteLayerForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    whiteLayerForm.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    whiteLayerForm.Opacity = 0.5;
}
```

You should be able to restore responsiveness to users action like clicks by moving any calls to this and other similar methods to a background thread.