# C# Set Windows Form to front but not give it focus

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, focus

I'm trying to make a notification system using windows forms and when a new notification pops up, I want it to be in front of whatever the current window is but to not have focus. How can I do this?

Comment: [Show a Form without stealing focus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/157843/7444103)

Comment: Slightly different, if no real interaction with the popup is required: [Form without focus/activation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764646/7444103) (setting `Style` to `WS_CHILD`). Useful when you need to show a partially transparent Form on top of another. Note that you can also use a PictureBox or a non-system Flat Label (similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51435842/7444103)).