# custom notification windows form without changing focus of current working window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have create form used as notification and it pops up when timer event ticked. Form has been set to topmost= true.
How can I make this form/notification show up without stealing current working windows focus?

Comment: you can redirect the focus back again to the current working form

Comment: @MongZhu, How I am suppose to do that?

Comment: [Show a Form without stealing focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156046/show-a-form-without-stealing-focus) -- [Form without focus/activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328962/form-without-focus-activation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show a Form without stealing focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156046/show-a-form-without-stealing-focus)

Comment: @Sinatr no, it didn't.